# `make -j `nproc`` in the build folder gives : `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.` macOS

Tags: makefile, cmake, openpose

I followed the installation guide and got the result as "Configuring done" in cmake GUI. I did this installation in Ubuntu18.04 local machine/laptop.

Installation guide link: https://medium.com/@alok.gandhi2002/build-openpose-with-without-gpu-support-for-macos-catalina-10-15-6-8fb936c9ab05#f7ce

when running "make -j nproc" inside the build folder, then getting below error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: You must run the `make` command in the directory that contains the file "Makefile".

Comment: Depending on [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) CMake may create projects for different build tools. Make utility works with "Unix Makefiles" generator.